# Disable Parental Control (Family Safety) Override?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, parental-controls

When the time limit is up, there is a box that says "Get more time." How do I disable/remove this box? I have tried going into the registry (regedit) and navigating to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Parental Controls\Users[UserID] (UserID being a long string of letters and number to specify the user). I added a DWORD and named it *Override Requests On* and modified the value data to *0* (I saw in other Users this DWORD). Yet the box still remains. Any ideas?

Or better yet, even how to remove a specific administrator from being able to grant more time?